# How to separate buttons in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I want to reuse my css code for my button and html code, and make another same style button but with different text in it. Is there a way to reuse the css code/html for a button and create another button that's the same as the previous one?

Code:

```css
body{
background: black;
}

.wrapper { display: flex; }

#container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 100px;
    }
    .button {
      margin-top: 58px;
      align-content: left;
      --y: -25;
      --x: 0;
      --rotation: 0;
      --speed: 2;
      --txt: "About Me";
      --padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: var(--padding);
      border: 4px solid;
      border-color: #00fffe;
      color: transparent;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      transition: background 0.1s ease;
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 50%);
              animation-name: flow-and-shake;
      -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
              animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
              animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    .button:after {
      content: var(--txt);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: var(--padding);
      color: #fff;
    }
    .button:hover {
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 40%);
      --speed: 0.1;
      --rotation: -1;
      --y: -1;
      --x: 1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes flow-and-shake {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * -1%), 0) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * -1deg));
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1%), calc(var(--y) * 1%)) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
      }
    }

    /* second button */
    #container2 {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      
    }
    .button1 {
      margin-top: 58px;
      align-content: left;
      --y: -25;
      --x: 0;
      --rotation: 0;
      --speed: 2;
      --txt: "Projects";
      --padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: var(--padding);
      border: 4px solid;
      border-color: #00fffe;
      color: transparent;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      transition: background 0.1s ease;
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 50%);
              animation-name: flow-and-shake;
      -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
              animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
              animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    .button1:after1 {
      content: var(--txt);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: var(--padding);
      color: #fff;
    }
    .button1:hover1 {
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 40%);
      --speed: 0.1;
      --rotation: -1;
      --y: -1;
      --x: 1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes flow-and-shake {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * -1%), 0) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * -1deg));
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1%), calc(var(--y) * 1%)) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()" >Show me attention</button>
  </div>
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()">Show me attention</button>
  <div class="button__shadow"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Even though I have different texts for each button, it still does not work. By the way, the css is what controls the text, and text is displayed in there. Ignore `Show Me Attention` in the HTML, as it does not do anything. I named the first button `About Me` but the second button `Projects`. However, they both have the same name for some reason. Is there a way to fix this? Also, nothing else should change as they should still be aligned beside each other.

Comment: Both buttons have the class of `button`, should not one of them have the class of `button1` ?

Comment: You could add multiple classes to your button HTML, and give each new one a specific ID or class particular to that button like `button1` and `button2`, just to change the text.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling your text via CSS is a very bad practice especially for primary content like buttons.

Your text is showing but because the text is set to transparent you can't see your text. That doesn't mean it's not rendering.

You can use the same classes, you don't need btn1 or btn2 or need to work with pseudo elements to display text.

See example.

```css
body{
background: black;
}

.wrapper { display: flex; }

#container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 100px;
    }
    .button {
      margin-top: 58px;
      align-content: left;
      --y: -25;
      --x: 0;
      --rotation: 0;
      --speed: 2;
      /* REMOVED: --txt: "About Me"; */
      --padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: var(--padding);
      border: 4px solid;
      border-color: #00fffe;
      color: white; /* changed */
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      transition: background 0.1s ease;
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 50%);
              animation-name: flow-and-shake;
      -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
              animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
              animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
   /* REMOVED
   .button:after {
      content: var(--txt);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: var(--padding);
      color: #fff;
    }
    */
    .button:hover {
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 40%);
      --speed: 0.1;
      --rotation: -1;
      --y: -1;
      --x: 1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes flow-and-shake {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * -1%), 0) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * -1deg));
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1%), calc(var(--y) * 1%)) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()" >About me</button>
  </div>
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()">My Projects</button>
  <div class="button__shadow"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duplicating all of your css code, you could add a specific class to your new buttons like `btn1` and `btn2`. Leaving the class `button` on everything that will remain the same. Where `btn1` and `btn2` are to change the text.

```
.btn1 {--txt: "About Me";}
.btn2 {--txt: "Projects";}
```

Here is your code updated and working on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e54g2w9q/

**CSS:**

```
body{
background: black;
}

.wrapper { display: flex; }


.btn1 {--txt: "About Me";}
.btn2 {--txt: "Projects";}

#container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 100px;
    }
    .button {
      margin-top: 58px;
      align-content: left;
      --y: -25;
      --x: 0;
      --rotation: 0;
      --speed: 2;
      --padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: var(--padding);
      border: 4px solid;
      border-color: #00fffe;
      color: transparent;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      transition: background 0.1s ease;
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 50%);
              animation-name: flow-and-shake;
      -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
              animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
              animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    .button:after {
      content: var(--txt);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: var(--padding);
      color: #fff;
    }
    .button:hover {
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 40%);
      --speed: 0.1;
      --rotation: -1;
      --y: -1;
      --x: 1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes flow-and-shake {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * -1%), 0) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * -1deg));
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1%), calc(var(--y) * 1%)) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
      }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button btn1" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()" >Show me attention</button>
  </div>
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button btn2" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()">Show me attention</button>
  <div class="button__shadow"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not just text, but I also want to add links to each button

Comment: Are you running Jquery on the site you are trying to accomplish this? If so you could just use: Jquery to do this. `$('.btn1').click(function() {
   window.location = "#URL#" + this.id;
});`

Comment: Could you please come on here: https://repl.it/join/utjcuhnv-hussainomer

Comment: @JCBiggar why are you promoting bad practice and using javascript to make links? Please teach people proper HTML and don't make stuff overcomplicated.

Comment: its jquery and its not bad practice, a large portion of ecommerce sites use it all the time. But Code287, you could also just add `onclick="window.location.href='#URL#'"` to the button html.

Comment: @JCBiggar jQuery is a JavaScript library.. so yes it is. Also you can just use href="#url#" that what the <a> tag is for. Absolutely no need to use any JavaScript for a simple HTML element.