# Animation in html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I would like the modal that pops up in my code to work separately for the buttons I have. For example, I have the `About Me` button and the `Projects` button. When the user clicks the `About Me` button, there should be a separate modal that pops up with different text, and then when the user clicks the `Projects` button, there should be a different modal that pops up with a different text. Essentially, the design of the modal should be the same, it just that it should have different text for each of the buttons.

Code:

```js
function popUp_model(){
    const pop_up_model = document.getElementById('model');
 pop_up_model.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
body{
background: black;
}
.wrapper { display: flex; }

#container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 100px;
    }
    .button {
      margin-top: 58px;
      align-content: left;
      --y: -25;
      --x: 0;
      --rotation: 0;
      --speed: 2;
      --padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: var(--padding);
      border: 4px solid;
      border-color: #00fffe;
      color: white; /* changed */
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      transition: background 0.1s ease;
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 50%);
              animation-name: flow-and-shake;
      -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
              animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
              animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
  
    .button:hover {
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 40%);
      --speed: 0.1;
      --rotation: -1;
      --y: -1;
      --x: 1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes flow-and-shake {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * -1%), 0) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * -1deg));
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1%), calc(var(--y) * 1%)) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
      }
    }
    
    
    /* modal*/
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body1 {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
}

#model {
  position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #101010;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 70px 50px;
  transition: 1s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#model.active {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
}
#model .model-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#model .model-content img {
  width: 80px;
}
#model .model-content h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
.model-input {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.model-input input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.model-input input[type="submit"] {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.model-input input[type="submit"]:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.close-model {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close-model img {
  width: 20px;
}


/* modal 2*/

/* modal*/
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body2 {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button1 {
  position: relative;
}
#subscribe-us1 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#subscribe-us1:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
#model1 {
  position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: steelblue;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 70px 50px;
  transition: 1s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#model1.active {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
}
#model1 .model-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#model1 .model-content img {
  width: 80px;
}
#model1 .model-content h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
.model-input1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.model-input1 input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.model-input1 input[type="submit"] {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.model-input1 input[type="submit"]:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.close-model1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close-model1 img {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()" >About me</button>
  </div>
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model()">My Projects</button>
  <div class="button__shadow"></div>
</div>
</div>



  <div id="model">
        <div class="model-content">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/mail-icon-260nw-523869661.jpg" alt="Email">
            <h2>
                Join Our Newsletter
            </h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </p>
            <div class="model-input">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="model-input">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="close-model" onclick="popUp_model()"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pyconic-icons-1-2/512/close-512.png" alt="Close-model-icon"></a>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is the same modal with the same text for both of the buttons. But I want different text on the modals for each of the buttons. Any suggestions?

### Expected Output

When the user clicks `About Me` the modal with the text that I sent in the code should appear.

When the user clicks `Projects` the modal with a different text saying something like, "Hello, these are my projects" should appear.

**NOTE:** The design of the modal should be the exact same, the only thing that changes is the text.

I tried switching the names of the classes and making like a second modal with different text but it did not quite work, and I got the wrong output.

Is there a way this can be accomplished?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reuse the same code multiple times - html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360283/how-to-reuse-the-same-code-multiple-times-html-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiples ways to reuse the same model with different content, based on the situation.

A simple solution can be passing some parameters to the `popUp_model` function.

```js
function popUp_model(typeOfModel) {

  let aboutHTML = `
     <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/mail-icon-260nw-523869661.jpg" alt="Email">
    <h2>
      Join Our Newsletter
    </h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
    <div class="model-input">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
    </div>
    <div class="model-input">
      <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </div>
  `;

   let projectHTML = `
      
    <h2>
      My Projects
    </h2>
    <ul>
       <li>Project 1</li>
       <li>Project 2</li>
    </ul>
   `;
   
   if(typeOfModel == 0)
      document.getElementsByClassName("model-content")[0].innerHTML = aboutHTML;
   else 
      document.getElementsByClassName("model-content")[0].innerHTML = projectHTML;
   
  const pop_up_model = document.getElementById('model');
  pop_up_model.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 100px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 58px;
  align-content: left;
  --y: -25;
  --x: 0;
  --rotation: 0;
  --speed: 2;
  --padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: var(--padding);
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: #00fffe;
  color: white;
  /* changed */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  transition: background 0.1s ease;
  background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 50%);
  animation-name: flow-and-shake;
  -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
  animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 40%);
  --speed: 0.1;
  --rotation: -1;
  --y: -1;
  --x: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flow-and-shake {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * -1%), 0) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * -1deg));
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1%), calc(var(--y) * 1%)) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
  }
}


/* modal*/

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body1 {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
}

#model {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #101010;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 70px 50px;
  transition: 1s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#model.active {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
}

#model .model-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#model .model-content img {
  width: 80px;
}

#model .model-content h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.model-input {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.model-input input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.model-input input[type="submit"] {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.model-input input[type="submit"]:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.close-model {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-model img {
  width: 20px;
}


/* modal 2*/


/* modal*/

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body2 {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button1 {
  position: relative;
}

#subscribe-us1 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#subscribe-us1:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

#model1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: steelblue;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 70px 50px;
  transition: 1s;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#model1.active {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
}

#model1 .model-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#model1 .model-content img {
  width: 80px;
}

#model1 .model-content h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.model-input1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.model-input1 input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.model-input1 input[type="submit"] {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.model-input1 input[type="submit"]:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.close-model1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close-model1 img {
  width: 20px;
}

h2, p, li {
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="button__wrap">
    <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model(0)">About me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="button__wrap">
    <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model(1)">My Projects</button>
    <div class="button__shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="model">
  <div class="model-content">
    
  </div>
  <a class="close-model" onclick="popUp_model()"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pyconic-icons-1-2/512/close-512.png" alt="Close-model-icon"></a>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to send the type and set the text in the function based on the type.

```js
function popUp_model(type){
  let changeTextEl = document.getElementById('change-text')
  if (type == 1) changeTextEl.innerHTML = 'Join Our Newsletter'
  if (type == 2) changeTextEl.innerHTML = 'Hello, these are my projects'
    const pop_up_model = document.getElementById('model');
 pop_up_model.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
body{
background: black;
}
.wrapper { display: flex; }

#container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin: 0 100px;
    }
    .button {
      margin-top: 58px;
      align-content: left;
      --y: -25;
      --x: 0;
      --rotation: 0;
      --speed: 2;
      --padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: var(--padding);
      border: 4px solid;
      border-color: #00fffe;
      color: white; /* changed */
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      transition: background 0.1s ease;
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 50%);
              animation-name: flow-and-shake;
      -webkit-animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
              animation-duration: calc(var(--speed) * 1s);
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
              animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
  
    .button:hover {
      background: hsl(var(--grey), 100%, 40%);
      --speed: 0.1;
      --rotation: -1;
      --y: -1;
      --x: 1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes flow-and-shake {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * -1%), 0) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * -1deg));
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate(calc(var(--x) * 1%), calc(var(--y) * 1%)) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
      }
    }
    
    
    /* modal*/
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body1 {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
}

#model {
  position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #101010;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 70px 50px;
  transition: 1s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#model.active {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
}
#model .model-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#model .model-content img {
  width: 80px;
}
#model .model-content h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
.model-input {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.model-input input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.model-input input[type="submit"] {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.model-input input[type="submit"]:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.close-model {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close-model img {
  width: 20px;
}


/* modal 2*/

/* modal*/
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body2 {
  background: transparent;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button1 {
  position: relative;
}
#subscribe-us1 {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#subscribe-us1:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
#model1 {
  position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: -100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: steelblue;
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 70px 50px;
  transition: 1s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#model1.active {
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
}
#model1 .model-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#model1 .model-content img {
  width: 80px;
}
#model1 .model-content h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
.model-input1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.model-input1 input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.model-input1 input[type="submit"] {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.model-input1 input[type="submit"]:hover {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.close-model1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close-model1 img {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model(1)" >About me</button>
  </div>
<div class="button__wrap">
  <button class="button" style="--hue: 162.03381670949574" onclick="popUp_model(2)">My Projects</button>
  <div class="button__shadow"></div>
</div>
</div>



  <div id="model">
        <div class="model-content">
            <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/mail-icon-260nw-523869661.jpg" alt="Email">
            <h2 id="change-text">
                Join Our Newsletter
            </h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </p>
            <div class="model-input">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="model-input">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="close-model" onclick="popUp_model()"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pyconic-icons-1-2/512/close-512.png" alt="Close-model-icon"></a>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```